# Pulling info from an external page

Tags: php, javascript, external, extract

Okay, bear with me. Part of my job is filling out online forms for customers who call in. In these forms there are all kinds of useful information that is hidden in input tags. I would like to make my own page that would extract and display all this useful information. I would also use this page to count the number of times I submit the form throughout the day.

The way I currently have it set up it is in a frameset. The left frame has links to the different forms we fill out, and when I click on one the external form is populated in the right frame. Javascript would be perfect for the job except that my frame is not located on the same server as the forms.

I stink at PHP. Not gonna lie. So i'm not looking for any hand-outs but any pointers would be great.

For example you may check out the forms on http://www.youcangetacar.com and you may use the pin code "A101" or you can check out what I have so far at http://customertrack.host-ed.me/

Comment: Would love to help, but I don't see a question here.

Comment: I'm curious as to why the forms and the result page don't live in the same domain.

Comment: @joseph the dreamer: these pages were written by my bosses goons. they were intended for customers. the url is sent to the customer in a flyer with whatever pin code corresponds to their dealer. some customers are lazy and would rather call us to do it for them. i created the framed page just to earn points with my boss and make my job easier.

Comment: @alex lunix: the question is how do i access info from external in a frame preferably, if at all possible uusing a client side language. i found this http://blog.makezine.com/2007/11/03/crossdomain-crossframe-javascr/ but i don't understand it well enough to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a page that cURL’s the page that is passed to it via url(curl.php?url=http://www.google.com) and then you dont have trouble with same domain policy.

Don’t forget to string replace relative urls with absolute urls.

eg, action="/submit/form.php" must become action="http://www.domain.com/submit/form.php"